# Redirect to url from user input

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to perform a really simple task, in wordpress. A user enters a number in a text field, and on click redirect to a url/input.

user input: `123456`

user redirects to `http://example.com/123456` (not `/?url=123456` etc).

I went over several answers here, but it seems that this is not simple as it sounds.

Thanks!

OK, I'm not a coder, hence not thinking as one :) BUT here goes:

In woocommerce I have thousands of coupons codes. I'd like to offer a redeem code that gives 100% discount, a free digital download. I'm using url coupons plugin which has the ability to add a product and a coupon on entering a certain page and then redirect to another page, let's say the purchase page.

going to http://example.com/free/ will add a product and a coupon and then go to purchase page. But this is just for one coupon. how to make this to happen for every coupon code?

So I figured to create redirection rules for each coupon and redirect all of them to a page that will add the product and coupon and go to purchase page.
If coupon is correct, it will be added and everything is cool. If coupon code is not valid, it will not have a redirect rule and will go to 404 page or another dedicated page.
Now I need to have the user enter coupon code and redirect.

```
enter code here
<form id="form">
<input type="text" id="my-code">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = function () {

var url = document.getElementById("my-code").value;

window.location.assign('/' + url);
}
```

Comment: `window.location.assign('/' + userInputValueHere);`

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: Why would you want such a thing. Smells like bad app design. Please describe your intentions and I'm sure we will help you to find optimal solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5675556/jan-rydrych please see above...

Comment: @JanRydrych you a describing an **[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/360627)** :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - I was asking about OP's intention, not offering any solution of mine prior to know what he wants to do. I think that more experienced developers should advise to prevent some bad practise ideas. But never mind, I take my previous words back :-)

Comment: @JanRydrych No, I agree with your message, I was just telling you that there is an actual name for that and linked to explanation :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thanks for the link about XY Problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just saw you edit your first message, with jQuery :

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<form id="soTest" action="registerCoupon">
    <input type="text" id="coupon" name="coupon" value="Coup123456">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
$('#soTest').submit(function(ev) {
    var coupon = document.getElementById("coupon").value;
    ev.preventDefault();
    window.location.assign('/' + coupon);
});
</script>
```

With PHP you can try :

```
<?php
    $link = "testLink";
    header("Location: http://aaa.fr/".$link);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! url goes to /registerCoupon?coupon=123456

I'm trying to have just the user input after the trail, but maybe that's not possible.

Comment: Actually, this is perfect and redirection rules can be added.
Thanks!